# $\int_{\mathbb{R}}f(x)+g(x) \;dx<+\infty$ iff $ \int_{\mathbb{R}}g(x)\;dx<+\infty$ and $\int_{\mathbb{R}}f(x)\;dx<+\infty .$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, improper-integrals

Let be $f,g\in C^0(\mathbb{R})$ such that $g,f\geq0$.

$$ \int_{\mathbb{R}}f(x)+g(x) \;dx<+\infty\quad {\rm iff} \quad\int_{\mathbb{R}}g(x)\;dx<+\infty\quad {\rm and}\quad\int_{\mathbb{R}}f(x)\;dx<+\infty .$$

When the functions are positive, this statement is true. Right?

Whithout $f,g\geq0$, is the implication $\Rightarrow$ true? I think that the answer is no, because I can find the indetermination $-\infty+\infty$.

Thanks for the clarification!

Comment: Without $f, g \ge 0$ the $\implies$ direction is definitely not true - take $f$ to be any function such that $\int_{\Bbb R} f(x) \, dx = +\infty$ and let $g = - f$.

Comment: The first lemma is true, the one you suggested is crucially false. It's basically the reason why the theory of integration is made like it is.